# How do APs deal with unencrypted data?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, encryption

If I'm trying to connect to a network and I was able to authenticate myself but I didn't have the key required for encrypting the data. And I'm trying to send something unencrypted to the AP, it should accept my proposal because I'm authenticated, right? But then If I don't meet the security context (because I have no key) how would it know? what does it check for?

Comment: @mvw I mean starting a session with a pre-shared key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The act of authenticating via WPA2 involves generating the encryption keys needed, so this doesn't come up in normal operation. It would only happen if a device was buggy or if someone was trying to attack the network.

WPA2 compliant devices will drop (ignore) any non-EAPOL, unencrypted data frames they receive.

**Update:** Oh, you're asking a WEP question in 2018. Okay.

In WEP, the receiver would throw away any data frames that don't have the "Protected" bit set in the Frame Control field of the 802.11 header. Or if the buggy sender was wrongfully setting that bit on a frame that wasn't actually encrypted, the attempted decryption process would produce a meaningless blob of bits that wouldn't match the ICV (Integrity Check Value) in the frame, so the ICV check would fail and the frame would be dropped.

This is why, back in the days of WEP, if you got the password wrong on a WEP network that only offered Open System Authentication, you'd still get Authenticated and Associated to the network, but you wouldn't get any connectivity; not even a DHCP lease. Early clients would just leave you in that broken state and let you figure it out on your own. Later/smarter clients would detect the situation and disassociate/deauthenticate you from the network or at least pop up some warning about "limited connectivity".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry If I wasn't clear on my question. but I meant a scenario similar to that in WEP open system authentication. The device is authenticated (i.e. like in a fake authentication). And now it can send packets to the AP, but It doesn't have any key to the network so if any packets are sent they will be in plain text right? I hope to understand on what basis then does the AP accept or ignore the packets?